# __init__ change parent class attributes

Tags: python

Really I confused, and it turned upside down my understanding of OOP in Python.
I don't understand whats going on.

Problem. I create a Parent class for some ViewSets:

```
class BaseViewSet(object):
    bindings = {}

    def __init__(self):
        # Check that inherited class have updates for bindings
        if hasattr(self, 'bindings_update') \
                and isinstance(self.bindings_update, dict):
            self.bindings.update(self.bindings_update)
```

After I inherit this class:

```
class ClientsViewSet(BaseviewSet):
    bindings_update = {
        'get': 'get_clients_list',
    }
```

Ok, it still looks normal yet.

```
import BaseViewSet

b = BaseViewSet()

>>> b.bindings
{}
```

But I don't understand what is going on after:

```
import BaseViewSet
import ClientsViewSet

>>> BaseViewSet.bindings
{}

c = ClientsViewSet()
>>> c.bindings
{'get': 'get_clients_list'}

>>> BaseViewSet.bindings
{'get': 'get_clients_list'}  # WTF O_O ???!!!

b = BaseViewSet()
b.bindings
{'get': 'get_clients_list'}  # I started cry here...
```

So I don't understand why creation of inherited class instance affected parent class properties. 
Really I got funny bugs, when one ViewSet with `bindings_update` affected another inherited ViewSets.

Help me, please.

## UPDATE

Big thanks to everybody, for your help.
Sure I forgot, that my `bindings` is class property, so when I changed it in `__init__` of subclass it changed inside all inherited instances.

So, solution, that I used to solve my problem:

```
from copy import deepcopy

class BaseViewSet(object):
    bindings = {'get': 'get_instance'}

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)
        """ `__new__` called first and create instance of class """

        # It is new instance of my class
        obj = super().__new__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Deepcopy bindings dict from inherited class to avoid override
        obj.bindings = deepcopy(cls.bindings)

        # Now I have deal with instance's copied `bindings`,
        # not with BaseViewSet.bindings
        if hasattr(cls, 'binding_updates'):
            assert isinstance(cls.bindings_update, dict)
            obj.bindings.update(cls.bindings_update)

        return obj

class UserViewSet(BaseViewSet):
    bindings_update = {'post': 'create_user'}

b = BaseViewSet()
>>> b.bindings
{'get': 'get_instance'}

u = UserViewSet()
>>> u.bindings
{'get': 'get_instance', 'post': 'create_user'}

>>> BaseViewSet.bindings
{'get': 'get_instance'}  # Olala, my bindings rescued :D
```

Comment: `bindings` is a static variable. Which means if you modify it in one class, you are modifying it for all classes. You should either move the lot into `__init__` or create a new dictionary that copies the values from the class one so that you are modifying that classes own bindings.

Comment: Yeap, I'm stupid. I change `__init__` to `__new__` in BaseVievSet and deepcopy `bindings` to created instance. Now it works as I wait it.

Comment: Also you should be able to go `self.bindings = deepcopy(self.bindings)` in `__init__`. There's no real reason to use `__new__` for this.

Comment: @shadow, sure, you're right, but my code here is simpified, I have some more difficult logic, so it's a reason, why I move it to `__new__`

Comment: That's fine then. Just making sure you were aware of the other way. I've created an answer based off the comment - feel free to mark my it as correct if it has solved your problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bindings` is a static variable. This means that if you modify it in one class, you are modifying it for all classes.

You should either move the lot into `__init__` or create a new dictionary that copies the values from the class one so that you are modifying that classes own bindings. That way when you update the dictionary, you'll be doing so *just* for that instance.

Answer (score 0):

`bindings` is an attribute of the *class*, not the object.
This is why changes to the `bindings` dictionary appear to affect the class --- because they *are* affecting the class.

If you want to assign data to an individual object, that's what the `__init__` method is for:

```
class BaseViewSet(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.bindings = {}
        if hasattr(self, 'bindings_update') \
          and isinstance(self.bindings_update, dict):
            self.bindings.update(self.bindings_update)
        return


class ClientsViewSet(BaseViewSet):

    def __init__(self):
        self.bindings_update = {
          'get': 'get_clients_list',
        }
        super(ClientsViewSet, self).__init__()
        return
```

Then, assuming you've imported everything appropriately:

```
>>> b = BaseViewSet()
>>> b.bindings
{}
>>> BaseViewSet.bindings
AttributeError: type object 'BaseViewSet' has no attribute 'bindings'

>>> c = ClientsViewSet()
>>> c.bindings
{'get': 'get_clients_list'}
>>> BaseViewSet.bindings
AttributeError: type object 'BaseViewSet' has no attribute 'bindings'

>>> b = BaseViewSet()
>>> b.bindings
{}
```

Note that you can no longer access `BaseViewSet.bindings`, since it's no longer a class attribute.
You'll have to make sure no *other* code tries to use that attribute.

Comment: Thanks, Kevin. Your advice works, but I want solution, that allow have no `__init__` in each child ViewSet, because I will have hundreds of it. You may review my solution from updated question, I real interested your opinion.